# Duplicate menu SEO issue

Tags: responsive-design, seo

I recently had a client tell me that their SEO company was saying that having multiple versions of the same menu on the page was negatively affecting their SEO rankings. I was a little confused by this at first, but the reason behind it is that the HTML for the desktop/tablet navigation is shown by default, then on mobile, the main nav is hidden with CSS and the mobile nav is shown, so there was always two menus in the actual HTML, but only one shown at any time.

The way I've avoided this problem so far is by moving the initial desktop menu links via JavaScript if and when the width is in the mobile breakpoint, and vice versa if the width goes out of the mobile breakpoint, I was wondering if there was a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

How's about a Bootstrap solution? That way the menu will be displayed only once.

Example Bootstrap Menu from [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle" type="button">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Bootstrap theme</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I was hoping to have some sort of tag/attribute to add to a duplicated menu or something along the lines of that, if this isn't possible then I'll stick to my JS solution, thanks though.

Answer (score -1):

I agree that Duplicate content in your site could be a hazard for your search engine rankings, even if it is as simple as a menu – the net that tries to catch out people scamming or keyword stuffing often catches simple errors and coding problems like this. 
One clever thing I always tend to do if I am worried is that I set up a robots.txt. with an extension that disables duplicate URL issues from the site. If used correctly, it will ban all duplicate URL issues from your site. Otherwise I know that we have used Google Webmaster Tools in the past to fix a few duplicate issues too.